# Xamarin Forms - Sqlite android Oreo runtime.JavaProxyThrowable

Tags: sqlite, exception, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-8.0-oreo

I am using `Sqlite` in a `Xamarin Forms Portable` project and I successfully run my application on `iOS` and `UWP`. On Android, I can run my application on a Android 6.0 emulator but in Android Oreo although app is installed, it crashes on startup. I am facing the following issue.

**Issue:**

> android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroidInternal:sqlite3_open_v2
>   (byte[],intptr&,int,intptr) at
>   SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroid.Open
>   (System.Byte[] filename, SQLite.Net.Interop.IDbHandle& db,
>   System.Int32 flags, System.IntPtr zvfs) [0x00000] in
>   <8dbf6ff85082469fb9d4dfaa9eae6b69>:0 at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection..ctor (SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform
>   sqlitePlatform, System.String databasePath,
>   SQLite.Net.Interop.SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, System.Boolean
>   storeDateTimeAsTicks, SQLite.Net.IBlobSerializer serializer,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] tableMappings,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   extraTypeMappings, SQLite.Net.IContractResolver resolver) [0x000a2] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0 at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionWithLock..ctor
>   (SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform,
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionString connectionString,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] tableMappings,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   extraTypeMappings) [0x0002e] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0
>   at project.Models.Database+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<.ctor>b__0 ()
>   [0x0001d] in <7df232f34ab8474d9153e3809af4eda8>:0 at
>   SQLite.Net.Async.SQLiteAsyncConnection.GetConnection () [0x00000] in
>   <563d605f9f014eeeb32fd4a27b4d142e>:0 at
>   SQLite.Net.Async.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0
>   () [0x00006] in <563d605f9f014eeeb32fd4a27b4d142e>:0 at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   :0 at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in
>   :0   at
>   mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run (Native Method)   at
>   mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6541)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (Zygote.java:240)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:767)

In order to create the connection:

```
 public Database(string databaseName)
        {
            var pathToDatabaseFile = DependencyService.Get<Interfaces.ISQLite>().GetLocalPathToFile(databaseName);
            var platform = DependencyService.Get<Interfaces.IPlatformProvider>().GetPlatform();

            _connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() =>
            new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(platform, new SQLiteConnectionString(pathToDatabaseFile, false)));
            _connection.CreateTableAsync<SqlitePage>().Wait();
        }
```

In every project `GetPlatform` and `GetLocalPathToFile`  are implemented:

```
    return new SQLitePlatformAndroid();
```

and

```
return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), fileName);
```

The packages I use for Sqlite are:

> - SQLite.Net.Async-PCL
> - SQLite.Net.Core-PCL
> - SQLite.Net-PCL

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should change to sqlite-net-pcl, since Android 6+, some permission have changed.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

I switched to this PCL, and everything works like a charm.